# how to get the top n% nodes indexed in neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j

As my title.Firstly, all nodes have already been indexed by a property named "degree",INT type,and now,i want to get the top n% nodes ordered by "degree". so, i want to know whether there is a simple and fast way to finish it, maybe via the index query..and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Cypher query:

```
START n=node(*)
RETURN n
ORDER BY n.degree ASC (or DESC)
LIMIT 10
```

This query will return the first 10 nodes ascendingly ordered by degree.